# Implication/function in set notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Can a function and an implication be used in set notation?

I have a function that maps to sets, $f(x) \colon A \to \{\{1,2\}, \{3\}, \{4,5\}\}$

I have to use set notation to get the elements of set $A$ that map to each element in $\{\{1,2\}, \{3\}, \{4,5\}\}$ using the function.

Something like
$$\{y \mid y \in A \land x \in B \Rightarrow  x ∈ f(y)\}$$

Is that valid set notation? Can I use implication in set notation and is it required there or does
$$\{y \mid y \in A \land x \in B \land x ∈ f(y)\}$$
do the same?

Comment: $f(x): A \to \text{blah}$ - do you mean $f: A \to \text{blah}$, or do you mean that $f: \{ \text{something containing $x$} \} \to \text{blah}^A$? The input to $f$ should not appear in the domain/codomain statement: for example, $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $x \mapsto x^2$, rather than $f(x) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $x \mapsto x^2$. The exception is if $f$ is indeed a function of one variable which outputs a function of one variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question what $B$ is, but I guess you're aiming for something like this:

$\{ y : y \in A \land \forall x(x\in B \Rightarrow x\in f(y))\}$, which I guess you could state more informally as $\{ y : y \in A \land x \in f(y), \forall x \in B\ \}$

You should have only one free variable ($y$ in this case) when expressing a set.

Explicitly stating it with the $\forall$ quantifier shows you how $x \in B \Rightarrow x \in f(y)$ is not equivalent to $ x \in B \land x \in f(y)$: if there exists some element $x$ such that $x \notin B$, $\forall x(x \in B \land x \in f(y))$ gives you the empty set.

As a final comment, if for some reason you are still wary of the implication, $P \Rightarrow Q$ is logically equivalent to $\neg P \vee Q $, so you could use a disjunction instead.

Comment: By the way, "weary" means "tired". "Wary" means "cautious of".

Comment: @PatrickStevens Oops, you're right! My bad